# replace all instances of &lt; and &gt; but not text between them

Tags: java, regex

How to extract the text between tags?

to get text inbetween tags, the below code works fine,

```
System.out.println("<text>google<text/>".replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "")); // gives google
```

Am trying the same for `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Am I missing anything for the below code?

```
System.out.println("&lt;aksdk&gt;google&lt;aksdk&gt;".replaceAll("&lt;[^.]*&gt;", ""));
```

PS: Am not using this for html parsing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use brackets to capture what's between the angle brackets and put it back by referring to group 1 using `$1` in the replacement string:

```
"&lt;aksdk&gt;google&lt;aksdk&gt;".replaceAll("&lt;([^.]*?)&gt;", "$1")
```

Important note: Use `[^.]*?` (rather than `[^.]*`), because `[^.]*?` is *non-greedy*, which means it won't skip over the first `&gt;` and match with the last `&gt;`, which would leave the first `&gt;`and  second `&lt;` intact - not what you want.

Comment: for text as "<tag> google </tag>", i need "google", but for "sample text <tag/>", I require the output as "sample text". I tried to use "<[^>]*>\\u0020*" for removing trailing space for the latter example, but how to check for both the examples?

Comment: I would use a separate replace call (not replaceAll() because regex is not required) and do `str.replace("<tag/>", "")`

Comment: The tag is generic, it can be any tag. The problem I'm facing is to parse text like this "<tag>this is a <tag> sample text <tag/>" the output should be "this is a sample text". But there are 3 instances here, space before, space after and space on both ends. Once I use a replace, then the tag itself is removed making the next use of replace impossible.

Comment: So in summary, you want to remove all tags from the input?

Comment: Yes, but the problem am facing is with whitespace.

Comment: Whitespace where? There is no whitespace in your example. The best and easiest thing to do is give an edge case sample of input and output. Can you please provide that?

Comment: Input 1: "<tag> This is sample </tag>" Output 1: "This is sample". But, on just removing the "<tag>" or "</tag>" I get " This is sample ". Input 2: "This is <tag/> sample", if I use regex with a whitespace before and after then, Output 2: "This issample". So I can't use "\\u0020<[^>]*>" or "<[^>]*>\\u0020" or "\\u0020<[^>]*>\\u0020". And also cannot use a separate replace again, as the tag will already be removed in first replace and I have no idea how many extra whitespace is left to remove.

Answer (score 1):

You're accepting too many characters in the `[^.]`, so you're matching the start of the first tag to the end of the second and removing the entire string. Try `[^&]`:

```
System.out.println("&lt;aksdk&gt;google&lt;aksdk&gt;".replaceAll("&lt;[^&]*&gt;", ""));
```